# Received data Parsing in Python

Tags: python

This is an assignment. So, if what I am asking is something I should figure out myself then lemme know! :)

The thing is that I am to send a complete directory which may have files and sub-folders to the server. To differentiate b/w binary data, filename and folder name. I have assigned specific key letters !,^,| before and after data. (receiving one byte at a time). Though this seems like a hack to what I am trying to do. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your assignment does not specify a byte-stream, you can also try the SFTP protocol. It's pretty neat with commands like MKDIR, CD, PUT, GET. You can iterate through your file structure, check whether its a folder or a file and appropriately send through commands to the server.

I recommend paramiko - http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

Comment: No, I have to use TCP sockets for data transfer. The problem that I am getting is that it finds !,^,| while reading data from the file. And thus the logic fails.

Comment: Are you sure that this needs to be done in a single stream of data or multiple? You can add text delimiters like "FOLDER:","FILE:" and send them individually.

Answer (score 1):

Compress it with gzip or similar before sending and unpack it after transfer. This will save you the hassle dealing with multiple files.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/archiving.html

Comment: No, I have to use TCP sockets for data transfer. The problem that I am getting is that it finds !,^,| while reading data from the file. And thus the logic fails.